# Absolutely positioned images breaking out of wrapper div

Tags: css, position, css-position

I have a set of transparent PNG images that sit on top of each other and the user can toggle them on and off.  Here is the working example.

https://www.betterinboone.org/interactive-map/

The images are absolutely positioned within a div that is relative positioned div wrapper.  When the browser is above a certain size, the images break out of the wrapper div and overlap into the footer.

Here is the applicable CSS and HTML code snippets:

```css
.boone-edc-interactive-map {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.boone-edc-map-layers {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.boone-edc-map-layers img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1.0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="boone-edc-interactive-map">
  <div class="boone-edc-map-layers">
    <div id="boone-map-state"><img class="boone-edc-map-states boone-edc-maps" src="https://www.betterinboone.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/boone-edc-states-boone-county-v3.png" alt=""></div>
    <div id="boone-map-roads"><img class="boone-edc-map-roads boone-edc-maps" src="https://www.betterinboone.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/boone-edc-roads.png" alt=""></div>
    <div id="boone-map-rail"><img class="boone-edc-map-railroads boone-edc-maps" src="https://www.betterinboone.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/boone-edc-rails-zoomed.png" alt=""></div>
    <div id="boone-map-airports"><img class="boone-edc-map-airports boone-edc-maps" src="https://www.betterinboone.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/boone-edc-airports-zoomed.png" alt=""></div>
    <div id="boone-map-ports"><img class="boone-edc-map-ports boone-edc-maps" src="https://www.betterinboone.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/boone-edc-ports-zoomed.png" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I fix the images from breaking out of the wrapper div into the footer but yet still act responsively using CSS.

The original solution I referenced appears to use .js to dynamically resize the images on browser window size change. I was hoping for a simpler solution just using CSS. In the end, I used a handful of media queries to change things as the browser window gets smaller. I thought there may be a solution with a couple lines of CSS, I was never able to find one and I needed to wrap up this project

Comment: Here is a working example of what I'm trying to do: https://whywaynecounty.com/transportation/location-transportation/

Comment: I can't see the issue you're talking about.

Comment: The original solution I referenced appears to use .js to dynamically resize the images on browser window size change.  I was hoping for a simpler solution just using CSS.  In the end, I used a handful of media queries to change things as the browser window gets smaller. I thought there may be a solution with a couple lines of CSS, I was never able to find one and I needed to wrap up this project.  Thanks

Comment: It would be most helpful, if you could provide a minimal working example showcasing your problem on an online code editor like [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/). The CSS alone is not of much help.

Comment: please share  working example code, because it looks fine on my screen/browser on jsfiddle or codepen (or anything of your liking)

Comment: In order to address this/help you it looks as if you should put a working/bad example right here in the question as a snippet since the referenced site does not appear (to me) to exhibit the issue - I see your not on the JavaScript so put it here without that and just the CSS

Comment: I have put in a start snippet for that but what exactly is meant by "wrapper div" is unclear to me.

Comment: i think it should used object-fit from image https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my initial comment, I "solved" the problem by using multiple media queries to readjust the max height as the browser window sizes down.  The page in question no longer displays the issue because of this - I needed to move on.  I was hoping for a more eloquent solution rather throwing a bunch of CSS at it.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure to understand your issues at 100% but maybe the css `object-fit` property can help you as following

CSS

```
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover /* or contain */
}
```

you can find more info about this property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_object-fit.asp)